# How do I capture ONLY dd/mm/yyyy on my calendar SelectionChanged event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, modalpopupextender

When I try run my asp.net page on my laptop, it captures dd/mm/yyyy.  But when I run it on a different machine it captures mm/dd/yyyy otherwise.  How do I make it to capture ONLY dd/mm/yyyy?

This is what I have so far in my function

```
protected void calDDate_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtDDate_PopupControlExtender.Commit(calDDate.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a format. ToShortDateString will use the current threads culture which in turn will be the current region on the local machine, unless overridden. To force a format you need to specify a format such as

```
String.Format("{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the globalization of your app correctly: The following will make it dd/mm/yyy since Mexico has that format. Change accordingly to your needs. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

In your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I might have something different format.  i.e. Tue, 01/04/2014